# Is there a way to edit a http hotspot link that's in a richtext field

Tags: lotus-notes

'Hi

I've got a richtext field which contains a number of 'http' hotspots which I want to change to 'https'.  I can use NotesRichTextRange.Findandreplace to replace the url's "http" to "https" but that just changes the text of the url and not actually the hotspot internally.

I suppose I could use a remove then a RichText.addText to replace it.  But I think I'd rather modify the hotspot if that's possible.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the help for the NotesRichTextDocLink class. There you will also fiond this info:

> To access a NotesRichTextDocLink object, use the
>   NotesRichTextNavigator methods in conjunction with the type
>   RTELEM_TYPE_DOCLINK

The easiest is to run your code in the debugger, stop after you get the DocLink object and inspect it in teh debugger.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried a few things but no luck.  When I post a url to the richtext field, it automatically becomes a hotspot.  I tried using RTELEM_TYPE_DOCLINK but it didn't find it.  So I thought I'd manually create a hotspot but that didn't find either one.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the Genii rich text API.